# C++ Code won't sort

Tags: c++, function, sorting

Below is my code, it won't sort and it's supposed to! I need to read the numbers from in the file in as a vector. Then translate it to an array and sort the array.

Does anyone know why?

```
using namespace std;

//function prototype
int readInput(vector<int> &);
void sort(vector<int>, int[], int);

int main()
{
  vector<int> values;
  int sum, avg;
  sum = readInput(values);

  const int SIZE = 1300;
  int arr[SIZE];

   // for (int count = 0; count < values.size(); count++)
   //   array[count] = values[count];


  sort(values, arr, SIZE);

  avg = sum / values.size();
  cout << "The average is: " << avg;

  return 0;
}

int readInput(vector<int> &vect)
{

  int count;
  int total = 0;

  ifstream inputFile("TopicFin.txt"); //open file

  if(!inputFile)
  {
    return 0; // if file is not found, return 0
  }

  while(inputFile >> count) //read file
    vect.push_back(count); //add to file

  for (int count = 0; count < vect.size(); count++)
    total+=vect[count]; //sum data in vector

  return total;

}

void sort(vector<int> values, int array[], int size)
{

  int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

  for (int count = 0; count < values.size(); count++)
    array[count] = values[count];

  for(startScan = 0; startScan < (values.size()-1); startScan++)
  {
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = array[startScan];
    for(int index = startScan + 1; index < values.size(); index++)
    {
      if (array[index] < minValue)
      {
        minValue = array[index];
        minIndex = index;
      }
    }

    array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
    array[startScan] = minValue;
  }
  for (int index = 0; index < values.size(); index++)
    cout << values[index] << " " << endl;
}
```

Comment: Which part of this isn't working? The file input? The sorting? Please help narrow down where the problem is by proving a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org).

(If you just need the average, you don't need to sort.)
(Just use `std::sort` instead of implementing your own sorting algorithm. It works on arrays as well as vectors.)

Comment: You are sorting the array, but you are outputting the vector values.

Comment: Why aren't you using the standard templated sort, instead of writing your own?

Comment: I'm an idiot. How do I output the array?

Comment: for (int index = 0; index < values.size(); index++)
    cout << arr[index] << " " << endl;
}

Comment: My apologies for being so myopic in my coding view. I appreciate all your help.